# Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H_1,H_2$ be subgroups. Show that $⟨H_1∪H_2⟩=\{h_1h_2∣h_1∈H_1,h_2∈H_2\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Could you please help me with my proof?
It feels incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it.

We need to prove that:

1. $⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩ ⊆ \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\} $
2. $ \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\} ⊆ ⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩$

1|
Let's take $x ∈ ⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩$, that is an element of the smallest group generated by $H_1 ∪ H_2$.
We can express $x$ as a product of elements from supgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ and since $⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩$ is a group $x$ can also be an inverse of that product. $x = h_1h_2$ or $x = (h_1h_2)^{-1}$

$(h_1h_2)^{-1} = (h_2)^{-1}(h_1)^{-1} = (h_1)^{-1}(h_2)^{-1} $

$(h_1)^{-1} ∈  H_1 \land (h_2)^{-1} ∈ H_2 ⇒  (h_1h_2)^{-1} ∈ \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\}$

which proves $⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩ ⊆ \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\} $

2| Let's take any element $y ∈  \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\} $, we know that it can be expressed as $h_1h_2$, but any product of elements from $H_1$ and $H_2$ must be contained in a group generated by $⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩$, thus $y ∈ ⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩$

Combining those two, we get $⟨H_1 ∪ H_2⟩ = \{h_1h_2 ∣ h_1 ∈ H_1, h_2 ∈ H_2\} $

Comment: Seems a little like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4721405/742), with a similar username (`abc` instead of `xyz`). Same person, or just two people doing the same homework assignment and having equal lack of interest and imagination with usernames?

Comment: If $x\in\langle H_1\cup H_2\rangle$, then $x$ can be written as $x=y_1y_2\cdots y_k$ for some $k$, where each $y_j$ is in $H_1\cup H_2$ or its inverse is. Do you see how that's more general than the expression you wrote for $x$? Can you see how to repair that step of the proof (the rest seems much more solid)?

Comment: "its subgroups" is the wrong terminology. It implies these are the only two subgroups. Just remove "its."